# Validation messages of extra fields in auth_user don't comply with available translations. Anyone else with this problem?

Tags: web2py

When creating extra fields for auth_user, the validation messages for those fields are always in English. They don't comply with the translations available.

This does not happen on the default fields.

I added this to db.py

```
auth.settings.extra_fields['auth_user'] = [
    Field('pagination',
          'integer',
          default=9,
          label=T('Pagination'),
          notnull=True,
          required=True,
          requires=IS_INT_IN_RANGE(5, 51),
    ),
]
```

When inserting an invalid value, the returned message is always

> ```
> Enter an integer between 5 and 50
> ```

even when the web2py language is not English and the languages files have the correct translation available.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was identified as a bug in the way some validators use the messages.
More details in the web2py group.
https://groups.google.com/forum/#!searchin/web2py/extra_fields%7Csort:date/web2py/7O_h5YotOsQ/cZ7OM43yCAAJ